# why can't Class.getSuperClass() method get exactly the super class type instance?

Tags: java, class, rtti

Assume there are two classes, namely `Pet` and `Dog`. `Pet` class is the superclass of `Dog` class.

Ques01:

When I coded as below, a compile error occurred: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<capture#2-of ? super Dog> to Class<Pet>`

```
Class<Pet> c1 = Dog.class.getSuperclass();
```

It has to be like this:

```
Class<? super Dog> c2 = Dog.class.getSuperclass();
```

Furthermore, when I use `c2.newInstance()`, it only returns an `Object` instance. Why can't I just get a `Class Instance` of `class Pet`?

Ques02:

When I System.out the `c2.getName()`, it outputs `"pet"`! So c2 just got the information  I want.

I'm really confused by these. Could anyone give any help? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reflexion API in Java is much older than generics. Some of the methods in RTTI reflect that.

Also, RTTI is a *runtime* feature and generics are a *compilation* feature. Sometimes, the compiler just doesn't have enough information to check if the runtime types will be correct.

However, for example your `newInstance` example is not valid.

```
public class Test {
    class Pet {}

    class Dog extends Pet {}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class<Dog> dogClass = Dog.class;
        Dog dog = dogClass.newInstance();
    }
}
```

Compiles with no problem, since on `Class<T>` the method declaration is `T newInstance()`

If we take the `getSuperClass()` example, you have to understand first that the compiler doesn't know what `getSuperClass()` does. It looks only at the method declarations. That's why it doesn't know that the class returned is really a `Pet`. It just compares the type of the variable with the type of the object returned by `getSuperClass`. The variable is `Class<Pet>` and the returned object is `Class<? super Dog>`, that's not the same. The compiler doesn't simulate the `getSuperClass` implementation and doesn't know the exact object returned.

Comment: yes, I know this example can work with `newInstance` method. I just get confused about the Class instance returned by `getSuperclass()`.            Since I just got a `Class<? super Dog> c2`, which can create an Object instance, at the same time, `c2.getName()` indicates that it indeed represents a `Pet Class`. So how can I get a Class<Pet> instance using c2? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Judking Of course you can. The compiler just doesn't know it. With `<? super T>` the method has to return `Object` because it is also a superclass of `T`.

Answer (score 0):

Too many questions into one post....

The general answer here is legacy and backwards compatibility. Generics have been introduced into java in version 1.5. Method `getSuperClass()` existed in java since version 1.0. The java creators could not break compatibility with older versions, so they did not change its prototype. This is why you have to cast `Dog.class.getSuperclass();` to `Class<? super Dog>` or something like that.

The same is about `newInstance()` that unfortunately returns plain object while it creates "correct" instance. So you have to cast in this case also. Therefore `getName()` returns correct class name: the class is indeed `Pet`.

Comment: This is wrong, `newInstance()` returns type `T`, and `getSuperClass()` return `Class<? super T>`.